# Output into file using CreateProcess with command line

Tags: c, output, createprocess

I follow a example in msdn to CreateProcess to execute command line. 
It works if I don't don't change output stream to a file.

It works with:

```
CreateProcess( NULL, COMMAND, NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);
```

COMMAND is marco that is dedined:

```
#define COMMAND ("REG QUERY \"HKLM\\Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run\" /s")
```

and I want to do this, but I is not successful:

```
#define COMMAND ("REG QUERY \"HKLM\\Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run\" /s > runssss.txt")
```

How can I change output of a command into file?

Thank for reading!

=========================================

**UPDATED SOLUTION**

Using `system()` command, that will execute multiple command.

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/58667/how-to-redirect-stdout-to-a-file-from-a-visual-c-c-program

Comment: `> file.txt` is a shell feature. When invoking a command, it is not executed in  a shell, thus the redirection does not work. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682499(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Thanks, I solved my problem!

Comment: @Haniz: you should consider to post and accept an answer to indicate that you no longer need help here.

Comment: Ok, thank for advice